# Google maps in PHP and JS clickable image - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the map I have in WordPress to be clickable, I would like it to link to another webpage, most likely Maps itself or another page on the site. I have tried a few JS codes but can't seem to get it to work.

```
window.marker = null;

function initialize() {
    var map;

    var Wolfeboro = new google.maps.LatLng(43.613717, -71.219710);

    var style = [ 
        { "featureType": "road", 
           "elementType": 
           "labels.icon", 


    var mapOptions = {
        // SET THE CENTER
        center: Wolfeboro,

        // SET THE MAP STYLE & ZOOM LEVEL
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom:10,

        // SET THE BACKGROUND COLOUR
        //backgroundColor:"#d5d5d5",

        // REMOVE ALL THE CONTROLS EXCEPT ZOOM
        panControl:false,
        scrollwheel: false ,
        zoomControl:false,
        mapTypeControl:false,
        scaleControl:true,
        streetViewControl:false,
        overviewMapControl:true,
        zoomControlOptions: {
        style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }

    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    // SET THE MAP TYPE
    var mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {name:"Grayscale"});    
    map.mapTypes.set('grey', mapType);
    map.setMapTypeId('grey');

    //CREATE A CUSTOM PIN ICON
    var marker_image ='<?php echo get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/images/pin.png';
    var pinIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker_image,null,null, null,new google.maps.Size(177, 159));   

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: Wolfeboro,
      map: map,
      icon: pinIcon,
      title: 'Sugar Hill'
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Is your map beeing displayed? So you initialized the map on an element with the id **map**. Why don't you just place that element inside an anchor, like this: `<a href="http://your-external-page.com"><div id="map"></div></a>`. Note that you have to give the element corresponding to the map (here #map) a height and width, otherwise it might not be displayed correctly.

Comment: Yeah its being display. This didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
url: 'http://www.google.com/',
map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
window.location.href = marker.url;
});
```